# FreeBSD out of box Screen/TMUX functionality?

Tags: freebsd, gnu-screen, tmux

Does FreeBSD include capabilities out of box that are similar to Screen or TMUX?

If so, what is the utility called?

**Update**: I'd rather not use Screen due to it licensing. TMUX is BSD-3 clause, which is great. But if FreeBSD includes similar functionality out of box, then I won't install TMUX.

Answer (score 2):

As i know, no such software in base.

pkg_add -r screen , and be happy

Answer (score 0):

window(1) used to be in base system, but was removed after 7.4-RELEASE:

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/window/Attic/README